# How to check activity is running first time or not

Tags: android, android-activity

My question tells everything.
Is there any idea about activity is installed first time.

actually I want to check whether activity is install first time  b'coz i am using one variable that check if installed first time it should be

> true

otherwise it changed

> false

Comment: Try out with sharedpreference.

Comment: @GrlsHu hello can you give me more idea ???

Comment: @Scientist, check my answer. You will get idea.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store data in "Preferences" like below code.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);

if (settings.getBoolean("is_first_time", true)) {
    //the app is being launched for first time, do something        
    Log.d("TAG", "First time");

    // first time task

    // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
    settings.edit().putBoolean("is_first_time", false).commit(); 
}
 else
{
    //second time launch..
}
```

When you launch your application first time, **if** condition will return **true**, because no data is stored first time and default value is **True**. So second time it will not execute due to **is_first_time** value **False**.

**Note**

Above code will reside in **onCreate** method.

Comment: Thanks 
Can you help another???

Comment: @Scientist, sure why not.. we are here to help people..

Comment: I will explain step wise so you can understand better
Steps:
 1. in onCreate -> startService
 2. in service -> using asyncTask(it store data to sqlite) (i want to display PrgressDialog as first time running apps)
 3. it after that using second asynckTask will display from sqlite.

Comment: come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era room.